# Outgoing Emails not working in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint, smtp, sharepoint-2019

> We have migrated Content from SP2013 to SP2019 but outgoing emails are not working specific to the migrated web applications but working for newly created web applications
>   Pinging from the server is working 
>   Sending mails from Server is also working

Answer (score 0):

Go to CA->Manage web applications->[migrated web application], click **General Settings**->**Outgoing E-mail**, make sure the mail settings are correct and not the old SMTP server.
[image]